# How to create a ruler a tool for canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Like the standard paint program in windows, I'm trying to create a very basic sketch canvas program where the  the user can select a ruler tool to draw with on the canvas. How do I achieve this?

I'm quite a beginner so I'd appreciate if the answer is as simple as possible...

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "ruler tool to draw with on the canvas"? Do you mean one that sits on the edge of the drawing area, or something else?

Comment: What you use to draw a line... So normally you'd get it alongside other  shapes like rectangle, circle, etc...

Comment: If I understand you correcctly, I'd view it as a 2 step problem. **1** generate the image of a ruler - I'd use a second canvas for that. **2** position and orient it in the direction of the line. - This is assuming that instead of a solid line, you want to draw an image of a ruler.

Comment: I just want the user to be able to draw a basic solid line exactly like the one in Paint. Is there a simple way of doing this using javascript?

Comment: Something like the answer here, perhaps? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/693236/unable-to-draw-more-then-1-shape-on-html5-canvas

Answer (score 4):

You can use 2 overlapping canvases wrapped in a container div.

Then draw your ruler marks on the bottom canvas.

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8hVC2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:315px;
        height:215px;

    }
    #canvasBottom{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    #canvasTop{
        position:absolute; top:15px; left:15px;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvasTop");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvasBottom");
    var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");

    ctx2.beginPath();
    for(var i=0;i<canvas.width;i+=10){
        var y=(i/100==parseInt(i/100))?0:10;
        ctx2.moveTo(i+15,y);
        ctx2.lineTo(i+15,15);
        var x=(i/100==parseInt(i/100))?0:10;
        ctx2.moveTo(x,i+15);
        ctx2.lineTo(15,i+15);
    }
    ctx2.stroke();


    var canvasOffset=$("#canvasTop").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#movelog").html("Move: "+ mouseX + " / " + mouseY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here

    }

    $("#canvasTop").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="movelog">Move</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvasBottom" width=315 height=215></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvasTop" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I may suggest you could use my [easyCanvas](https://github.com/epistemex/easyCanvas) library. It's a library that wraps around standard canvas and let you use it as ordinary but adds some handy functionality (GPL3).

If this is an option you could create what you need simply by doing this assumimg the easyCanvas script is already included:

```
var ez = new easyCanvas();

// enable background handling when drawing
ez.autoClear = true;

// mouse down/up is handled internally so all we need to draw the line
ez.onmousemove = function(e) {
    ez1.line(ez.firstX, ez.firstY, e.x, e.y);
}
```

(you can use an existing canvas element as well - this will create a canvas that covers the window and auto-resizes it when window size changes, please see [documentation](https://github.com/epistemex/easyCanvas/docs.html) for the details).

**Update**: easyCanvas is now legacy and is located at GitHub to avoid link-rot.